# Entity Framework Core bug? SaveChanges throw select

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I'm working with Entity Framework Core and .NET 5 and I detect some memory increased flows in server. When I see the console log, I see the problem, when a `SaveChanges` call fails, it throws a select of all tables and all records :(

My database is huge and full the memory. I've been searching the internet but couldn't find any similar error.

I hope someone has a solution. Thanks

The logs:

> [10:59:45 WRN] Compiling a query which loads related collections for more than one collection navigation either via 'Include' or through projection but no 'QuerySplittingBehavior' has been configured. By default Entity Framework will use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery' which can potentially result in slow query performance. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2134277 for more information. To identify the query that's triggering this warning call 'ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning))'
>
> [10:59:46 DBG] Generated query execution expression:
> 'queryContext => new SingleQueryingEnumerable(
> (RelationalQueryContext)queryContext,
> RelationalCommandCache.SelectExpression(
> Projection Mapping:
> SELECT t.Id, t.AceptaTerminosYCondiciones, t.Activo, t.ContactoPrincipalId, t.CreatedBy, t.CurrentTimestamp, t.DateCreated, t.DateEdited, t.EditedBy, t.EstadoId, t.PersonaHumanaId, t.PersonaJuridicaId, t.TipoPersonaId, t.TipoSujetoObligadoId, t.UsuarioId, p.Id, p.CreatedBy, p.Cuit, p.CurrentTimestamp, p.DateCreated, p.DateEdited, p.EditedBy, p.FechaConstitucion, p.Jurisdiccion, p.NroInscripcion, p.RazonSocial, ....

Comment: Should we investigate why a SaveChanges fails instead?

Comment: SaveChanges would not normally run a select after failing. This select is probably being triggered by SaveChanges before the fail, to get some missing information necessary to generate the insert/update queries

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing the class model and mappings and the generated query.

Comment: the problem is that the select that it generates when it fails brings me several gigabytes of records. there is no way to disable that?

Comment: When my code throw DbUpdateException Ef genereted queryes for all tables and my memory flow incress to much. But if query dont throw de error this selecets dont excecute. I tried put a interception but  the selects execute before.

Comment: Well, obviously there's something thoroughly wrong with your model, but again, show it if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I traced it down to Sherilog's ExceptionDetails sink.

Serilog.Exceptions is serializing DbUpdateException, which can result in an attempt to traverse the entire graph of objects associated with the exception. If you remove .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails() from the Serilog config,then things work as expected.

Please see the details here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15214

Comment: You are right, when I removed the  .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails() from serilog, EF save changes console log disabled.